# X11 for CrossOver on Mountain Lion

Tags: x11, macos

In my newly-installed Mountain Lion system: when I try to run CrossOver, which requires X11, I get the following error message:
[image]

Apple's Web Page indicates that this is not the expected behavior:

> ## X11 install on demand
>
> X11 on Mountain Lion now uses install on demand. When you first launch an app that requires X11 libraries, you are directed to a download location for the most up-to-date version of X11 for Mac.

Does anyone know how to download X11 for Mountain Lion?

Comment: Time to put the GIMP back in it's box :(

Comment: This appears to be an issue with CrossOver – not an issue with Apple's method of directing the user. Please, which version of CrossOver did you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Apple's dialog for X11 does not appear, you can [grab the package directly from the XQuartz website](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X112.7.2).

Version 2.7.1 was the first to support Mountain Lion, but 2.7.2 is the current release as of this writing.

Comment: Is this the official download?

Comment: @DanielLawson Yes, it's the one Apple links to.

Answer (score 5):

Normally, Mountain Lion should show the following window:

[image]

Clicking Continue just takes you to http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5293, so simply go there for official instructions for installing X11.